# Moving a list in a loop to a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, for-loop

I am tring to get "portlist" into a string as I need it for a command in the script.

I have tried using join, taking it out of the loop as a global var without success.
I am always getting it as a list shown below.
`2
3
4
5
6
7
8
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
18
19
20
21
22
23
24`

```
        if 'On' in line:
            portlist = []
            tempportlist = []
            port1 = line.split(':')
            port = str(port1[0])
            port = port.strip(' ')
            servername = (str(port1[1]))
            servername = re.sub(r"\s+", "", servername)
            pattern = re.search(r'(?!E000)[A-Z]([^\sPDU]+)\d', str(port1))
            tempportlist.append(pattern)


            try:
                for val in tempportlist:
                    if val != None:
                        with open(full_path, 'r') as fgclistfile:
                            if servername.lower() in fgclistfile.read().lower():
                                portlist.append(port)
                                portlist = str(portlist).strip('[\'''\']')

                                #print portlist,
                                global temp
                                temp = ''.join(portlist)
                                #temp = ''.join([str(newport) for newport in portlist])
                                print temp

                            else:
                                print "Not found"               
                #print temp
            except StopIteration:
                pass
```

I want to get
`2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,18,19,20,21,22,23,24`
into a single string.

Comment: Try to run `rstrip()` on each port string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved `portlist = []' outside of the loop and that gave me one list of the ports.

```
def findservername():
portlist = []
if 'On' in line:
            tempportlist = []
            port1 = line.split(':')
            port = str(port1[0])
            port = port.strip(' ')
            servername = (str(port1[1]))
            servername = re.sub(r"\s+", "", servername)
            pattern = re.search(r'(?!E000)[A-Z]([^\sPDU]+)\d', str(port1))
            tempportlist.append(pattern)


            try:
                for val in tempportlist:
                    if val != None:
                        with open(full_path, 'r') as fgclistfile:
                            if servername.lower() in fgclistfile.read().lower():
                                portlist.append(port)
                                global temp
                                print temp

                            else:
                                print "Not found"               
                print portlist
            except StopIteration:
                pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment this this :

```
portlist = str(portlist).strip('[\'''\']')
```

And put this after the for loop finishes:

```
temp = ','.join(portlist)
```

.join() method takes a list as parameter, not a string.

EDIT:

This should be your loop code:

```
            for val in tempportlist:
                if val != None:
                    with open(full_path, 'r') as fgclistfile:
                        if servername.lower() in fgclistfile.read().lower():
                            portlist.append(port)
            ports_str = ','.join(portlist)
            print(ports_str)
```

Comment: output is still vertical and without commas. `2
3
4
5
6
7
8

10
11
12
13
14
15
16

18
19
20
21
22
23
24`

Answer (score 0):

You are overwritting you `portlist` with each iteration, when you do:

```
portlist = str(portlist).strip('[\'''\']')
```

Try the following to watch you list growing with each iteration:

```
portlist.append(str(port).strip('[\'''\']'))
temp = ','.join(portlist)
print temp
```

Move the `print temp` out of the loop to get the complete list printed once.

Comment: Nice, this got me the list but not a string.

Comment: Still it is not reproducable for us, as you do not give the complete information. Can you privde the output?

Comment: sure, the output is the same as before `2
3
4
5
6
7
8
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
18
19
20
21
22
23
24`

Comment: Looks like a string to me. If it was a list, something like `[2, 3, 4, ... , 24]` would be printed. Have you used the join correctly? Mine is different than your, because I use `','` as seperator.

Comment: I have. the thing is that the output is horizontal and does not have commas between the numbers

Comment: What does the output of `print portlist` look like?

Comment: Vertical output. `[]
['2']
['3']
['4']
['5']
['6']
['7']
['8']
[]
['10']
['11']
['12']
['13']
['14']
['15']
['16']
[]
['18']
['19']
['20']
['21']
['22']
['23']
['24']`

Comment: This indicates that within each loop you get a list with only one string as entry. Is there another `for` loop in which the shown code is embedded?

Answer (score 0):

I taken `portlist=[]` from the loop and added it before the loop and the issue was resolved.